# I'm having a problem trying to export multiple XLS Sheets each into it's own csv file in R

Tags: r

I'm kinda new to R and i just can't seem to figure out how to do it. I have a function that opens up an XLS file, and converst it into a list of dataframes - each sheet is it's own dataframe. Now i want to export these into different CSV files for each sheet. Here's my code:

```
preberiXLS<- function(potDoXLS,tibble = FALSE){
  
  tryCatch(expr = {path1=potDoXLS
  excel_sheets(path1)},error=function(e){print 
    "Input mora biti excelova datoteka"})
  
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(potDoXLS)
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(potDoXLS, sheet = X))
  if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)

  names(x) <- gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", sheets)
  
 
  write.csv(x,paste0("HW3Data/",names(x),".csv"))

  x

 
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
preberiXLS<- function(potDoXLS){
  
  tryCatch(expr = {path1=potDoXLS
  excel_sheets(path1)},error=function(e){print 
    "Input mora biti excelova datoteka"})
  
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(potDoXLS)
  lapply(sheets, function(X) {
    write.csv(readxl::read_excel(potDoXLS, sheet = X), 
              paste0(X, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
  })
}
```

I don't think it really matters if the data is dataframe or tibble while writing it to csv.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I felt quite dumb when i read your solution.. Of course my code didn't work, I only wrote the first sheet as csv and didn't apply it for all of them.